# T-SQL Stored procedure with OUTPUT parameter giving an error

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is defined as

```
create procedure p1
(
    @id INT,
    @name varchar(20) OUTPUT,
    @company varchar(20) OUTPUT
)
AS
     BEGIN
        select @name = name, @company = company from table1 where id = @id;
     END
GO
```

I call it using

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20), @company varchar(20), @id INT;
exec dbo.p1 @id=2, @name OUTPUT, @company OUTPUT;
select @name AS 'NAME', @company AS 'COMPANY'
```

However I get an error

```
'Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brother, I am not sure what you're trying to select but maybe you can try the query below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1
(
@id INT,
@name varchar(20) OUTPUT,
@company varchar(20) OUTPUT
)
AS
 BEGIN
Set @name = 'name'
Set @company = 'company'
    select @name , @company from table1 where id = @id;
 END
GO
```

Answer (score 14):

Follow the instructions in the error message:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20), @company varchar(20), @id INT;
exec dbo.p1 @id=2, @name = @name OUTPUT, @company = @company OUTPUT;
select @name AS 'NAME', @company AS 'COMPANY'
```

---

Alternative - don't name parameter 1:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20), @company varchar(20), @id INT;
exec dbo.p1 2, @name OUTPUT, @company OUTPUT;
select @name AS 'NAME', @company AS 'COMPANY'
```

---

From [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

> When used with the *@parameter_name=value* form, parameter names and constants do not have to be supplied in the order in which they are defined in the module. However, if the *@parameter_name=value* form is used for any parameter, it must be used for all subsequent parameters.

(Because, obviously, the first usage might be defining any parameter, so it can no longer assume that any subsequent ones should be assigned in order)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  I would also add, to avoid confusion, that in the "caller" code you should name your variables differently than the parameters.  Something like this:  "exec dbo.p1 <at>id=2, <at>name = <at>outName, <at>company = <at>outCompany".  PS: forgive the silly substitution, I didn't remember that comments couldn't contain code or >1 at-symbols.

Comment: Okay fine, I read the help... `exec dbo.p1 @id=2, @name=@outName, @company=@outCompany`  Thanks for the push!

Answer (score 2):

change to this will work

```
    DECLARE @name varchar(20), @company varchar(20), @id INT;
    select @id=2
    exec dbo.p1 @id, @name OUTPUT, @company OUTPUT;
    select @name AS 'NAME', @company AS 'COMPANY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for your question.

Please try in this way. It will work fine.

**Procedure**

```
alter procedure my_pro
@id int,
@name varchar(30) output,
@email varchar(50) output
as
begin
select @name=Name,@email=EmailID from Users where id=@id
end
```

**Execute**

```
declare @Newname varchar(40)
declare @Newemail varchar(40)
exec my_pro 2,@Newname output, @Newemail output
select @Newname 'Name', @Newemail 'Email'
```